# Example of Lightning web Component with LWC container

Tags: lightning-web-components

Salesforce just only provided how to call the component in LWC container but no actual example. May anyone already implemented container, please provide the example.

Below example from salesforce guide link
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_compose

My question is can we define c-todo-wrapper component to call c-todo-item component.

```
<!-- todoApp.html -->
<template>
    <c-todo-wrapper>
        <c-todo-item item-name="Milk"></c-todo-item>
        <c-todo-item item-name="Bread"></c-todo-item>
    </c-todowrapper>
<template>

<!-- todoWrapper.html -->
<template>

        <c-todo-item item-name="Milk"></c-todo-item>
        <c-todo-item item-name="Bread"></c-todo-item>

<template>

<!-- todoItem.html -->
<template>
   Name {itemName}
<template>
```

Comment: its not clear what you are asking. Can you show some documentation reference or code sample?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

In the example you have provided:

```
<!-- todoApp.html -->
<template>
    <c-todo-wrapper>
        <c-todo-item item-name="Milk"></c-todo-item>
        <c-todo-item item-name="Bread"></c-todo-item>
    </c-todowrapper>
<template>
```

1. `todoApp` is the owner component of `todo-wrapper` and `todo-item`
2. `todo-wrapper` is the container of `todo-item` but not owner.

> My question is can we define c-todo-wrapper component to call
>   c-todo-item component.

**Yes**. You have to use `this.querySelector` and `this.addEventListener` as `todo-item` is not owned by it.

For detailed example on the differences in the way you identify elements and add event listeners from owner or container components you can refer to [LWC: Difference between "window" and "this"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273296/lwc-difference-between-window-and-this)

**ADDED BASED ON COMMENTS:**

```
<!-- todoWrapper.html -->
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

You can also use named slots in which case, you have to mention in which slot the components have to be injected. You can refer to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots

Comment: Again I updated my question - Is wrapper component defined correctly? No issue with Parent-child but parent-wrapper-child is confusing me.

Comment: added in answer

Comment: as per answer what will deference between then parnet-wrapper-child and parent-child-child? How your definition of wrapper call will fulfill the definition of wrapper class?                                                                                                  
Container
 A container can:
Read, but not change, public properties in contained components
Call methods on composed components
Listen for some, but not necessarily all

Comment: In parent-child-child, you will not be using slots and thereby removing the dynamic nature of wrapper component

Comment: A slot can be used on a child as well not just for the wrapper class. A slot used for replacing the markup in a child component from the parent. I used the slot in opening Modal from the parent component. Might be I am unable to correlate wrapper example in Apex with LWC wrapper.  let me go try to create one example based on your suggestion.

Comment: you can use slot anywhere. Do not think in terms of apex wrapper - its completely different. When you use slot in child then child becomes container in the owner component which creates another component to be injected inside slot of child.